# Why is this comment not deleted?

Tags: discussion

[Link to comment in question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/148382/editor-invited-to-decision-in-process#comment394160_148382)

I've already flagged the comment, but it's still there, so I'm guessing the moderators decided it's acceptable. I don't see why. It effectively associates World Scientific with predatory publishing based on no evidence (the scenario described by the question-asker certainly does not look like predatory publishing to me).

I suppose the reason Anonymous Physicist even drew the connection in the first place is similar to  Debora Weber-Wulff's reasoning: "World Scientific" seems like an awfully broad name for a journal. Problem with that is that [World Scientific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Scientific) isn't a journal, but a publisher. One could argue that the name still implies the publisher is predatory, but this publisher (see link) was established in 1981. That's well before predatory publishing existed.

The way I interpret it, the comment is similar to answering every university-related question with "first make sure you're not attending a degree mill", or every professor-related question with "first make sure the professor is actually qualified to teach this subject". These statements may be *true*, but they're also *rude*, and should not be said.

Can the moderator who declined the flag please explain his/her reasoning?

Comment: Note that I moved the entire ongoing debate about World Scientific to chat now (not singling out any comment).

Comment: **Moderator’s Notice:** Please take any debate about the actual reputability of World Scientific [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107446). Any comments and answers debating this will be deleted. Use this question and answers for debating whether such comments should be deleted. For the purpose of this question, it should not matter whether we are talking about World Scientific, Elsevier, Wiley, Springer, etc. Or: If your opinion of World Scientific could be deduced from anything you post, it does not belong here.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft if we generalize to include all publishers then the comment is even more inappropriate since it insinuates that every publisher is predatory.

Comment: The moderator's notice could be interpreted as implying that I claimed the publisher was predatory.  I would like it to be clear to those who cannot see deleted text that I do not make any such claim.  I think we all agree that claims of predatory behavior which are not factual would be libelous.

Answer (score 4):

This was me.

**Background: Moderation.** According to StackExchange's [Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/), moderators are supposed to do "as little as possible." In particular, we do [not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89453/should-moderators-delete-bad-answers) delete bad answers, only pointless noise. The power belongs to the community; we are only "human exception handlers" (or, perhaps, garbage collectors). Further, we generally "assume good intent," though I don't think this is codified any longer.

**Background: Comments.** There are various reasons why comments can be deleted, but we try very hard to avoid adjudicating issues and deleting the comments from the losing side. We certainly don't think censorship is what the community wants. In cases like this, I would suggest that you instead post a rebuttal comment (take to chat if it leads to a long discussion).

**This case.** In this case, your objection seems to be about rudeness/libel: you feel that the poster should not have raised the issue of predatory journals when there is no indication that the (named) publisher is predatory. While I share your concern about "associating [the publisher] with predatory publishing," you are suggesting that we should have single-handedly deleted the comment. For a comment to be deleted by a moderator on the grounds of rudeness or libel, the comment needs to be manifestly unacceptable.

In this case, however, we do not really know why the poster decided to raise a concern about predatory publishing. It could be because of the publisher's name, as you suggest. But it could also be for some other reason altogether, that has nothing to do with the publisher. Perhaps the comment author surmised (fairly or unfairly) that OP's "real question" was "Did I submit to a predatory journal?" and chose to provide some links that might be helpful. Or perhaps the suspicion about being predatory was because of the one-week turn around (this would indeed be suspiciously fast for peer review to be completed, though it's not suspicious for a desk rejection, which is probably what happened here).

**Conclusion.** I am certainly not endorsing this comment -- it could well be completely unhelpful, or merely confuse the issue. But I believe this is the sort of thing that the community should discuss, not the sort of "exception" that I should smite with my mod-hammer. I stand by my decision, and would encourage you to post a comment on the original post vouching for the publisher's credibility. (Another option would be to edit the question to remove the publisher's name altogether).

Comment: Commenting on the original post vouching for the publisher's credibility would be introducing something unrelated though - the question doesn't touch on disreputable publishers at all, and it would be like commenting asking what the OP's gender is just to make sure the (probable) desk rejection isn't due to gender bias, etc.